# Limitations on Waypoints in Here-Maps SDK & Routing Performance measurement

Tags: navigation, here-api

I am using Here-API for navigation,Can I know the maximum waypoints that an routing API supports..
(I tried adding 100 waypoints still routing is fine so bench mark i need this info)

Also how can i measure here maps performance for calculation of the route.
(Currently I am adding the logs at the time of request and calculation complete callback)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please edit your question by adding more details about your problem and provide code example of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Here Routing API accepts upto 200 waypoints in a single request. Performance of the api query depends on several factors like the number and the complexity of the attributes requested for, the number of route alternatives requested, client bandwidth, etc. So its hard to provide a fixed number. Hope this helps!