# Limitation for waypoints when using HERE Route Matching v8

Tags: here-api

[Limitations on Waypoints in Here-Maps SDK & Routing Performance measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647832/limitations-on-waypoints-in-here-maps-sdk-routing-performance-measurement)
I am using HERE Route Matching v8 and having the same question.
Is there still the limitation of 200 waypoints in a single request now?
Thanks.

I want to know the Limitation for waypoints when using HERE Route Matching v8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. We would suggest you use waypoints with small sizes, and you are right the current limitation is still under 200 waypoints, this restriction is on the URL characters limitation, not the request itself.